# How to display payment information with PayPal IPN WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, paypal-ipn

I using plugin for wordpress - IPN PayPal and I want to display on my Home site list with payments. I wont to use to this paypal hooks.

```
    <?php

add_action('paypal_ipn_for_wordpress_ipn_response_handler', 'process_recurring_handler', 10, 1);

function process_recurring_handler( $posted )
{
    // Parse data from IPN $posted[] array
    $first_name = isset($posted['first_name']) ? $posted['first_name'] : '';
    $last_name = isset($posted['last_name']) ? $posted['last_name'] : '';
    $mc_gross = isset($posted['mc_gross']) ? $posted['mc_gross'] : '';
    $recurring_payment_id = isset($posted['recurring_payment_id']) ? $posted['recurring_payment_id'] : '';
    $payer_email = isset($posted['payer_email']) ? $posted['payer_email'] : '';
    $txn_id = isset($posted['txn_id']) ? $posted['txn_id'] : '';

    /**
     * At this point you can use the data to generate email notifications,
     * update your local database, hit 3rd party web services, or anything
     * else you might want to automate based on this type of IPN.
     */
}


?>
```

This I add to function.php but how this call to be displayed the appropriate data in the table on page?
I tried by

```
<?php do_action('paypal_ipn_for_wordpress_ipn_response_handler')?>
```

But it doesn't work.
I'm totally laic, help

Answer (score 1):

The hook/function you're showing here would be triggered when any IPN hits your site.  You can use it to automate your own procedures based on the IPN being triggered.  It won't display anything to the site page/post itself.

If you want to display IPN data on your page/post content then you'll need to use the shortcodes that are provided by the plugin.  Check out the Shortcode options in the plugin's [developer guide](https://www.angelleye.com/paypal-ipn-wordpress-developer-guide/).

For example, if you want to display the last 10 IPN records you would use this shortcode:

```
[paypal_ipn_list field1="txn_id" field2="payment_date" field3="first_name" field4="last_name" field5="mc_gross"]
```

Comment: Nice. Thx.
But if I want to use payment to raffle, how to pull the data about payment?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your goal is.  Are you trying to update your database based on IPNs that hit, send out emails, or what exactly?

Comment: I use your plugin to see donations in wordpress admin panel. But I want use the data transferred by your plugin in raffle among donators. But I don't know what I can pull the data from plugin in admin panel. :(

Comment: The data for IPNs will be sent to your site and saved in the PayPal IPN list.  If you want to display the data on a page you'll need to use shortcodes like what I mentioned above.  If you want to automate procedures automatically when the IPN hits you would need to setup hooks in your functions.php or in your own plugin.